# List to quoted string

Tags: dart

I need to convert `List` to quoted string. My code is:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];
  String str = "INSERT INTO (" + list.toString() + ") VALUES (...) ";
  print(str);
  
}
```

output:

```
INSERT INTO ([aa, bb, cc]) VALUES (...)
```

But I need:

```
INSERT INTO ("aa", "bb", "cc") VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];
  String str =
      "INSERT INTO (" + list.map((e) => '"$e"').join(', ') + ") VALUES (...) ";
  print(str); // INSERT INTO ("aa", "bb", "cc") VALUES (...)
}
```

Can also be done like this which are a little shorter:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["aa", "bb", "cc"];
  String str =
      "INSERT INTO (${list.map((e) => '"$e"').join(', ')}) VALUES (...) ";
  print(str); // INSERT INTO ("aa", "bb", "cc") VALUES (...)
}
```

I should add that this is just a solution for solving your specific problem. For real SQL escaping from unknown input, you should take into account that the String can contain `"` and need to escape it correctly.

Comment: I guess, you need a join anymore @julemand. See my solution. :)

Comment: You need the join. See my comment on your solution ;)

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since you have an apt answer, and I want your answer to be accepted. My answer would become an inefficient duplicate code of yours. Hahaha! Thanks for the answer. **Just question => Any idea, why it doesn't show up all the data for the long string**?

Comment: @Alok "Returns a string representation of **(some of)** the elements of this.": https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/toString.html . I don't know why but the behavior is fully explained. :)